# Não consigo validar a hora atual do computador com IF ELSE, no Dart

Tags: if, flutter, dart

Estou tentando fazer uma validação no dart, onde a minha função `timevalider()` tem uma variável do tipo `dynamic`, onde ele se adapta com o que eu colocar.

Estou fazendo a seguinte atribuição `time = new DateTime.now().toIso8601String()`, pois com isso eu pego a hora atual do meu computador, que é retornado, por exmeplo:

`2020-04-03T16:05:29.620`

Eu fiz uma condição onde me retorna o texto "Bomdia", caso o `time` for menor e igual a 6.

Porem quando eu executo ele aparece esta mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia arrumar este erro, estou boiando em alguma coisa? Tem como fazer isso de alguma maneira diferente, poderiam me auxiliar na construção disso?

Segue o Código:

```
class Personagem{

  String nome;
  String povoado;
  int level;
  String classe;
  String habilidade;


  void levelskill(){
    level++;
  }

  //Só para assinantes
  void levelskillx4(){
    level +=4;
  }

  void renascer(){
    print("$nome morreu e renasceu no altar");
  }

  void death(){
    print("Você morreu! você perdeu uma porcentagem de level");
    level--;
    print("$level");
  }

   //Só para assinantes
  void premium(){
    print("Parabens $nome, agora você é premium, você tem 31 Dias.");
  }

  void timevalider(){
    dynamic time = (new DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    if( time <= 6 || time <= 13){
      print("Morning");
    } else if (time >= 13 || time <19){
      print("Good Afternoon");
    } else print("Good Night");
  }
}

void main(){

Personagem pessoa1 = Personagem();

  pessoa1.nome = "testeper";
  pessoa1.povoado = "canada";
  pessoa1.level = 5;
  pessoa1.classe = "mago";
  pessoa1.habilidade = "Magia e Controle";

  print(pessoa1.nome);
  print(pessoa1.povoado);
  print(pessoa1.level);
  print(pessoa1.classe);
  print(pessoa1.habilidade);

  pessoa1.premium();

  pessoa1.timevalider();
  print(new DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o método `.toIso8601String()` que irá retornar a data e hora em `String`, e logo em seguida você está utilizando essa `String` para fazer operações numéricas com os operadores `>=`, `<=`, o que não faz sentido, por isso o erro.

Sugiro modificar seu método `timevalider()` para o seguinte:

```dart
void timeValidator(){
  final time = DateTime.now();
  if(time.hour <= 13) {
    print("Morning");
  } else if(time.hour > 13 && time.hour <19) {
    print("Good Afternoon");
  } else print("Good Night");
}
```

Não tem porque usar o dynamic nesse caso, então deixe o tipo como `DateTime`, e com a propriedade `hour` é possível pegar a hora. Assim seu código vai funcionar.

Note que você fazia `time.hour <= 6 || time <= 13)`, o que também é desnecessário pois se é <= 13 já é <= 6.

Comment: Deu certo não sei nem como agradecer, o que seria essa função "final" ??

Comment: Mas novamente agradeço, agora entendi o meu erro grotesco, estou gostando a linguagem como um todo, viu desculpa posso so te perguntar mais uma coisa?  é possível ter funções de entrada no dart? tipo um scanf igual da linguagem c